# Using null inside Coldfusion Array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, null, coldfusion-9

I'm creating a array and need use null values

```
<cfset addLinha[1] = qEspecialidades.especialidade>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#numColumnsAntes#">
    <cfset arrayAppend(addLinha,null)>
</cfloop>
<cfset arrayAppend(addLinha,LSParseNumber(LSNumberFormat(AvgNota, "_.__")))>

<cfloop index="i" from="#numColumnsDepois#" to="#qEspecialidades.RecordCount#">
    <cfset arrayAppend(addLinha,null)>
</cfloop>
```

I need a array something like this

```
 ["Especialidade",null,null,null,null,4.0,null,null,null]
```

But I haven't found how to append `null`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need `null` as opposed to a placeholder value like ""? Just wondering if a different approach would serve you better...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ColdFusion does not have a null per se. Depending on what uses this variable, one or more of the following may be useful:

- Use a javaNull: `<cfset javaNull = javaCast( "null", 0 ) />`
- Use a blank: `""`
- Use an empty struct ie `{}`

Ben Nadel has [some comments on this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1654-Learning-ColdFusion-9-IsNull-And-Working-With-NULL-Values.htm) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can "append" a null value by increasing the size of the array with `arrayResize()` like so:

```
<cfset len = arrayLen(myArray)>
<cfset arrayResize(myArray, len+1)>
```

Comment: smart hack, but I would not do it.  I'd rather skip the index, and let CF/JVM handles the resize.

Comment: can you elaborate on why you would not recommend this method?

Comment: on 2nd thought, I think this is fine. Sorry can't undo the down vote unless there's an edit